# Prevent parent from being resized by child

Tags: wpf, layout

is there a possibility to prevent a textblock from resize it's parent?
I have a textblock with a lot of text and I want it to wrap, but not to enlarge the parents size. The size of the parent may be variable.
Greetings Thomas

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no Property for this feature.

The only workaround that I'm aware of is to either use an existing control or place another hidden control in the same space and then bind `Width` of your `TextBlock/TextBox` to the `ActualWidth` of that control.

Here is an example when the `TextBlock` doesn't effect the `Width` of the `ColumnDefinition` but it will get wider if the `ColumnDefinition` is resized for another reason

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
               TextWrapping="Wrap"
               Text="{Binding ...}"
               Width="{Binding ElementName=sizingControl, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
    <Rectangle Name="sizingControl" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="Hidden" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Funny thing btw. Just one hint: Using ActualWidth killed my CPU. Using Width fixed it.

Comment: Using this "workaround" usually requires a little testing. Sometimes setting the Margin to 1 for the `TextBlock`, sometimes using a `FallbackValue` in the Binding etc. It all depends on your scenario. Otherwise it can go into an infinite sizing loop like you noticed :) The sizingControl is resized so the `TextBlock` updates its `Width` which in turn resizes the sizingControl and so on. But I do believe `ActualWidth` should be used for this to work. Apprently using `Width` worked in your scenario so that's great :)

Answer (score 1):

For this to work, you need to set a width on the parent or place another grid or some container inside the parent which holds the textblock. Then set a width on that. The textblock will not wrap on a flexible parent.

Or better yet, just set a width on the textblock.

Comment: I know this approach, but there are some circumstances that make it impossible. Is there not just a little property or something..?