# Prevent wrapping TextBlock from affecting layout

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, textblock, word-wrap

I've run into this issue a few times and have yet to find a simple solution.  When a `TextBlock` (with `TextWrapping="Wrap"`) is embedded inside another element that doesn't specify its width, the `TextBlock` expands as large as its parent allows instead of first trying to wrap its text.  For example, I'm currently working on a `TextBlock` `ValidationTemplate`.  Here's how the template currently handles text longer than the width of the `TextBox`:

[image: Current validation template]

which is obviously not optimal.  Here's how I'd like it to appear:

[image: Desired validation template]

Here's the XAML for the `ControlTemplate` that's producing the first layout:

```
<ControlTemplate>
  <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <Border DockPanel.Dock="Top" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
      <DockPanel>
        <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="TargetTextBox" />
        <Grid x:Name="WarningBoxContainer" Background="Red" Width="{Binding ElementName=TargetTextBox, Path=ActualHeight}" Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Width}">
            <Path Margin="5" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Data="F1 M 26.9166,22.1667L 37.9999,33.25L 49.0832,22.1668L 53.8332,26.9168L 42.7499,38L 53.8332,49.0834L 49.0833,53.8334L 37.9999,42.75L 26.9166,53.8334L 22.1666,49.0833L 33.25,38L 22.1667,26.9167L 26.9166,22.1667 Z "/>
        </Grid>
      </DockPanel>
    </Border>
    <Border DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="0,2,0,0">
      <TextBlock Text="Something very terrible has happened" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    </Border>
  </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Does anyone know how to make a `TextBlock` wrap before trying to expand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, minutes after I post, I find the answer.

I got the idea of using a binding to enforce the width of the `TextBlock` from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300975/prevent-parent-from-being-resized-by-child) post.

In my case, binding the `TextBlock`'s width to the `ActualWidth` of the `AdornedElementPlaceholder` element did it:

```
<ControlTemplate>
  <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <Border DockPanel.Dock="Top" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
      <DockPanel>
        <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="TargetTextBox" />
        <Grid x:Name="WarningBoxContainer" Background="Red" Width="{Binding ElementName=TargetTextBox, Path=ActualHeight}" Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Width}">
            <Path Margin="5" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Data="F1 M 26.9166,22.1667L 37.9999,33.25L 49.0832,22.1668L 53.8332,26.9168L 42.7499,38L 53.8332,49.0834L 49.0833,53.8334L 37.9999,42.75L 26.9166,53.8334L 22.1666,49.0833L 33.25,38L 22.1667,26.9167L 26.9166,22.1667 Z "/>
        </Grid>
      </DockPanel>
    </Border>
    <Border DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="0,2,0,0">
      <TextBlock Text="Something very terrible has happened" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="{Binding ElementName=TargetTextBox, Path=ActualWidth}" Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Width}"/>
    </Border>
  </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

The end product:

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks! I tried it with width attribute only but height is neededas well.